# How to provide test coverage with Karma runner while proxying through a server

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, karma-runner

When testing javascript apps, I often find myself using a local test server to serve files in order to allow ajax request during the test (as `ajax` fails on the `file://` system).

This mean though that the served files ain't available through Karma runner when testing, and as so, they can't be instrumented to allow code coverage.

Anyone came across the same problem and found a solution? (instrumenting files from server, or enabling ajax request via Karma runner without using a server)